# How to send non-encoded data from web browser form

Tags: url-encoding

I need to send non-encoded data from web browser.
In Postman, I can send `' or 1=1--` without encode it.
But when I enter the string in the form using a web browser, It will be automatically encoded into `%27+or+1%3D1--`. I don't know how to send `' or 1=1--` from a web browser because the string's decoded value is the same. How to make the browser send the string as `' or 1=1--` instead of `%27+or+1%3D1--`?

Comment: And why exactly would you want to do that? Browsers automatically encode non-safe character strings.

Comment: It's only for testing.

Comment: what's the content type? If you're posting using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as your content type, the browser will automatically encode it. Instead if you use `text/plain` - you might get a chance to send as is